# Android RadioButton display

Tags: android, radio-button

This question has been posted before last year but the answers were not helpful to me.

Is there a way to make the RadioButton double-circle with green center to indicate selection not display? I want the user to just see a background image, instead of that image with the circle button over it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Call `setButtonDrawable()` on the `RadioButton` to be whatever you want. For it to work, it will need to be a `StateListDrawable` with all of the appropriate states. You can see the existing drawable resource -- it is `btn_radio.xml` in your Android SDK installation. Copy that into your project, copy the PNGs for the states into your project, adjust the PNGs to be whatever you want, and call `setButtonDrawable()` to reference your customized `StateListDrawable` resource.
From the XML, this can be done using the `android:button` property.